# Is there a floating-ruler app for macOS?

Tags: macos, graphics, space, graph

I’m working with a notation software and I would need to space certain graphical elements evenly within a predetermined space (e.g.: I set a 5cm space and I have 5 elements, they need to be precisely 1cm from each other), something that the software cannot do on its own (that is, without printing on paper, measuring, then moving the objects, then printing again and so on...).

The ideal solution would be to have a floating ruler on the screen or a superposed grid similar to millimetric paper that would still allow click-through (i.e.: interaction with the program below it).

Is there an app that provides this tool?

Thank you very much

Comment: I’m not sure if [OmniGraffle](https://www.omnigroup.com/omnigraffle) can do this, but it was the first app that popped into my head as a possibility.

Answer (score 23):

I've used [Free Ruler for Mac OS X](https://www.pascal.com/freeruler/) in the past. I'm amazed that still works just fine. However, it does not allow click-through.

Comment: what a beautifull simple little piece of software <3

Comment: Works great, and it does inches/cm!

Answer (score 7):

Not Exactly a ruler app but using the built in Command+Shift+4 screenshot tool can help too.

Comment: How exactly would the built-in screenshot help to solve the problem described in the question?

Comment: When you are defining the area to select, it shows the dimensions of the selected area. See this nice demo: https://www.ctrl.blog/entry/how-to-osx-screen-shot-ruler.html

Comment: This would be really a nice option.

Comment: @Neela Yes It can be handy sometimes to make quick check specially.

Comment: This! It's quick, built-in, free, and always at hand. Got the job done for me. Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

## iconfactory's [xScope](https://xscopeapp.com)

[image]

> Powerful on-screen rulers for precise pixel measurements that include scaling, rotation, and edge snapping.
>
> xScope’s rulers can be used to measure any on-screen element, including the distance and angles between objects. Holding down the Control key while dragging the ruler near an on-screen object causes the edges and ends of the ruler to “snap” into place, making measuring quick and easy. Additionally, the Ruler tool includes calipers which can be toggled on or off and used for outside measurements.

Not sure if non-pixel measurements are possible.

Comment: This can only display measurements in Screen pixels or Window points.

Comment: Finding out conversion from pixels to cm or inches for an application is quite difficult. For example, a 27, 32 and 49 inch screen with the identical resolution need very different rulers.

Answer (score 4):

Have a look at:

> ## [Ondesoft Screen Rulers for Mac](https://www.ondesoft.com/rulers/)
>
> ***Easy, powerful and accurate virtual screen rulers for your Mac***
>
> Ondesoft Screen Rulers is a highly configurable measuring utility for
> Mac with many intuitive features, enable you to  measure objects
> quickly and precisely on your Mac screen in Pixels, Inches, Picas,
> Centimeters and multiple customizable units according to your need. It
> can measure square areas, diagonals and display angles.
>
> - Online measuring tool to measure the dimensions of any objects on Mac.
> - Easy protractor enables you to measure angles in radians or degrees with Ondesoft Screen Rulers.
> - Detail Window provides you a magnifier and pixel value for accurate measurements.
> - Logger Window serving as your personal notebook can remember all the detailed measurements data history.
> - Customize keyboard shortcuts, ruler colors and transparency settings according to your preference.

Has a free trial, $9.95 USD to buy.

<sub>Note: I am not affiliated with the developer of this software. Simply a Google search.</sub>

Answer (score 4):

Free Ruler has been updated for macOS Catalina. It’s free and open-source: http://www.pascal.com/software/freeruler/

Then there’s [PixelSnap](https://getpixelsnap.com/) for $40 (that’s $10 cheaper than xScope and comes with seemingly superior dimension measurement engine).

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work in Mac OS Ventura - warning appears that it can't be checked for malicious code and it needs to be updated. Bummer.

Answer (score 3):

I have found these two free utilities.
They kind of do what I need but are very basic so anything more would be overkill for them.
- Red Line Tools.
- Ruler on Call EZ

Both available on the Mac App Store.

Comment: Red Lines Tools is both free and fantastic. Exactly what I needed for making measurements in my app's UI. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

[Shottr](https://shottr.cc/) is a screenshot measurement and annotation tool

One of its features: *Use it as a Screen Ruler*

```
brew install --cask shottr
```

[image]